# Google Form Api. Adding Response validation to textQuestion

Tags: google-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

Currently, AFAIK, when performing google form `batchUpdate` using the `google forms API v1`, we are only able to set the `shuffle` property of `choiceQuestions`, while for `textQuestions` there are no options to set the `response validations`, like if I want to use `regex match` as `validation`.

For Example, the request body looks like this:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createItem": {
        "item": {
          "questionItem": {
            "question": {
              "choiceQuestion": {
                "shuffle": false
              },
              "textQuestion": {
                "paragraph": false
                  /*no other parameters to set*/
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is this feature not implemented yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this has not been implemented yet. For now, [these](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms#choicequestion) are the only options that can be used with `ChoiceQuestion` This is kind of expected taking into consideration `FORMS API` was [launched](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/03/google-forms-api-generally-available.html) just last month.

So you may want to submit a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/support#missing_features) for that missing feature.

In the meantime, you can also consider tackling this using Google Apps Script and its `Forms Advanced Service` which includes [response validation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder)

Comment: So, would it be possible to create a `Google App script` with some `Forms Advanced Service` operations and then run the script using `Google  App Script API`?

Comment: Yes, you can create a ```Google App Script``` with the ```Forms Advanced Service``` and run it using the Google Apps Script API, you can see more details [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)

Comment: @YancyGodoy can plese explain little more i'm trying to get regex from google form api for a making chat bot

Comment: @MarlonDumal-is how you implement form api and app script together can you expain

Comment: @abhijithv as the comments imply you'll have to learn more about Google App Script API, you basically create an appscript function and run that externally through Google App Script. It's kind of hard to explain through comments. Best way to understand what we were discussing is by learning about google Apps script 1st.

Comment: @MarlonDumal-is can you suggest some doc or video releted to this topic I'm tring to get google form questions regex from api so I can make a bot and validate all qestion that user answer

Comment: @MarlonDumal-is is your project is open source can i have your github link to refer how to implement this